# Angularjs controller initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, declaration, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I am learning AngularJs. I am creating my first application on Plunker but it fails to initialize the controller. what am i missing exactly?

[Here is the link of my plunker project](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVDnSXT87AZjvUIccbEE?p=preview)

```
    <html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testcontroller">
  <h1>Hello {{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>

var testcontroller = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "world";
};
```

Comment: <html ng-app>.. here you need to give app name..

Comment: That is not necessary as long as i m not using modules

Comment: You need it man.. go to documentation of AngulaJS

Comment: I got it. using ng-App without module name was working flawlessly with previous releases like 1.3.0-beta.5 but Angular no longer supports this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjHa9R6Yfv1VyaMt2qH4?p=preview)

Declare `ng-app="myApp"`

You are defining controller in wrong way

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('testcontroller', function($scope){
  $scope.message="world";
});
```

Comment: is it mandatory to assign a module for the application? because i have seen many examples working with only ng-app

Comment: modular approach separates the code better way https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module